# A hard Lefschetz theorem for nilCoxeter algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, coxeter-groups, bruhat-order

Let $W$ be a finite Coxeter group and $\mathcal{N}(W)$ its nilCoxeter
algebra (over the reals, say), as defined at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nil-Coxeter_algebra. $\mathcal{N}(W)$ has
a natural basis $\{u_w\colon w\in W\}$. We have a grading
$$ \mathcal{N}(W)=\mathcal{N}(W)_0\oplus \mathcal{N}(W)_1\oplus
      \cdots, $$
where $\mathcal{N}(W)_i$ is spanned by all $u_w$ for which
$\ell(w)=i$, where $\ell$ is the length function of $W$. My question
is the following: does there exist an element $\theta\in
\mathcal{N}(W)_1$ such that for all $0\leq i< N/2$ (where $N$ is
the length of the longest element $w_0$), the map $\theta^{N-2i}\colon
\mathcal{N}(W)_i\to \mathcal{N}(W)_{N-i}$ given by $v\mapsto
\theta^{N-2i}v$ is a bijection?

This result (if true) is an analogue of the hard Lefschetz theorem for
the cohomology ring of a complex projective variety. However,
$\mathcal{N}(W)$ is not such a cohomology ring since multiplication
does not have the right commutativity properties. If the result is
true, then the weak order on $W$ satisfies the Sperner property, which
I believe is still open even for the symmetric group.

If $\theta$ exists, then of course a generic $\theta$ will
suffice. However, such results are difficult to prove for generic
$\theta$. Perhaps we can simply take $\theta=\sum u_i$ (where the
$u_i$'s are the generators of $\mathcal{N}(W)$). There is reason to
believe that for the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$, a good choice
of $\theta$ might be $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} iu_i$.

**Addendum.** A more detailed and explicit version of this question is now available at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00851.pdf.

**Second Addendum.** The problem has been solved in
https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00321,
https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.05501, and
https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05126.

Comment: Do you like to have $0\leq i\leq\lfloor\frac{N}2\rfloor$? It might be complete when $N$ is odd.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: when $N$ is even and $i=N/2$, the map $\theta^{N-2i}$ is the identity, so no problem.

Comment: I'd say it's more closely analogous to hard Lefschetz for the cohomology of the _flag_ variety $X$ on which $\mathcal N(W)$ acts (in the crystalographic case of course). In particular, it feels like it should be related to whether $\theta^{N-2i}:H^{2(N-i)}(X) \to H^{2i}(X)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Oops, I meant "complex projective variety," not "projective toric variety." This has been corrected.